# Iterator throws KeyNotFoundException

Tags: vb.net, iterator, ienumerable

I created my own iterator (the first ever) in order to transform the contents of a generic list. It looks like this:

```
Private Iterator Function ConvertList(x As MyObject, something) As IEnumerable(Of MyObject)
   For Each item As MyObject In Me.MyObjectList
      If(item.Equals(x)) Then
         Continue For 'Dont need this object
      ElseIf(some condition)
         Yield item 
      Else
         Yield DoSomeTransformations(item)
      End If
   Next Item
End Function
```

Now, what happens when I execute it on a List(Of MyObject) with 3 items:  It takes a first element, goes to the yield statement as intended. Then, instead of going to the 2nd element, it throws a KeyNotFoundException on the "Next item" statement ("The given key was not present in the dictionary").

This puzzles me. I do use some Dictionaries, but the collection here is a List(Of T). Hence, I figure it must be some internal representation.  If I remember right, List(Of T) implements IEnumerable(Of T), so For Each should be possible right?  Nevertheless I tried to solve by using AsEnumerable(), as well as trying a normal For loop, rather than the ForEach.  Both didn't seem to help. Now, I am kind of out of ideas.

Can anyone give me clue?

Edit:
The calling code is quite simply:

```
  Dim newList As List(Of MyObject) = ConvertList(...).ToList()
```

The call stack:

```
Mydll!MyClass.ConvertList() Line 203    Basic
mscorlib.dll!System.Collections.Generic.List<MyObject>.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyObject> collection) + 0x34f bytes  
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList<MyObject>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyObject> source) + 0x86 bytes   
Mydll!MyClass.SomeFunction(MyObject x) Line 162 + 0x28 bytes    Basic
```

The stack trace:

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
>
>   at MyClass`1.VB$StateMachine_0_ConvertList.MoveNext() in D:\Workspace\MyClass.vb:line 203
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
>   at MyClass`1.SomeFunction(MyObject x) in D:\Workspace\MyClass.vb:line 162

Okay, so the exception now makes slightly more sense. I suppose it is indeed an internal representation, although I do not really get why that is used. It indeed fails on the movenext. Is there a way that I can debug and see what kind of key it is fetching? Or what this internal dictionary looks like?

Comment: The code snippet is rather insufficient.  It also matters how this iterator is being used, Linq extension methods can use a dictionary.  Post at least the code that uses the iterator and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: You're right. I provided the relevant part of the call stack and the calling line of code. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Post the *complete* call stack, we need to see the frames above ConvertList.  Disable Just My Code if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the stacktrace was any different from the call stack. Just My Code was already disabled.

Comment: So, any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of someone else I managed to find out that the error in fact did not occur at the position it seemed to occur. In fact, the exception was thrown in the part where the transformations were done and probably caught by a try-block in the iterator implementation.

I think the lesson learned is: never trust the location of an exception. Changing the settings when the debugger breaks helped me there. (Alt-Ctrl-E in Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a bracket

```
 If(item.Equals(x)) Then
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. But that's obviously not the answer. I just typed that manually, so I could remove implementation details...